# Can "__compat layer" halt viruses?

Tags: windows, batch-file, virus

In Windows we can use set `set __COMPAT LAYER=RunAsInvoker` to stop applications from getting administrative privileges. So if I use this on a virus executable then will it stop the virus from affecting the system.
I also use an administrator password so virus will not be able to take administrative actions by any means I think

---

Another thing is can it access my system files or not? I know that virus will affect my system but will it be able to do anything with the system files? Thank you for your previous answer. Let me tell you my main target is to make the severity level as low as possible.

Comment: not necessarily.  the setting is primarily for suppressing UAC prompts, regardless of whether the app needs admin or not. if it does, it will error out. if the app doesn;t require admin, it may still run as with admin capabilities if the parent process it is run under is high integrity. https://packageology.com/app-v/supressing-uac-prompts-in-appv5-with-compat-layer/ so No, it is not a one-size-fits-all solution to making things run as low-integrity.

Comment: I use an administrator password so I think virus not be able to do any thing I think and I have done a experiment that is i used obs studio and tried to install it in program files as a result it couldn't install it cause it had no administrator power with the the code compat layer

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? UAC already stops the virus from executing as administrator unless you explicitly allow it. I can't see what else your idea brings to the table.

Answer (score 3):

> Can "__compat layer" halt viruses?

No, absolutely not. Certainly malware could do greater damage when run as Administrator, but it can already do plenty of damage otherwise. Ransomware is an excellent example.

Malware could also piggyback onto a different elevation request.

> In Windows we can use set set __COMPAT LAYER=RunAsInvoker to stop applications from getting administrative privileges.

You actually cannot. As I describe in [my answer to a different question](https://superuser.com/a/1735415/219095), `__COMPAT_LAYER` only affects the initial program launch. It will not stop a program from programmatically relaunching itself immediately, requesting elevation (still with a UAC dialog of course).

The only thing stopping (legitimate) applications from getting admin rights is *you* clicking *No* on the UAC prompt.

Keep in mind that even malware could be code-signed.

Comment: I use administrator password so will it be able to do anything then. Moreover  I have done a experiment that is i used obs studio and tried to install it in program files as a result it couldn't install it cause it had no administrator power with the the code compat layer

Comment: Another thing is can it access my system files or not? I know that virus will affect my system but will it be able to do anything with the system files?

Comment: Thank you for your answer in advance

Comment: @jastyles The installer may not have been built to work around your unusual handicap, but that doesn't mean it couldn't be. This is explained in the linked question. No, it can't access your system files, but that's not that much of improvement: system files are "cheap", they can be easily restored if needed. The worst case scenario is you lose some time to reinstall Windows. But your personal files are freely accessible without admin privileges and unless you have a good backup strategy (you should!), once they are gone, they are gone.

Comment: thanks @gronostaj

Comment: @jastyles Maybe I haven't explained it clearly. System files are important, but they are replacable. If they get damaged and you don't have backups, you can reinstall the OS and that's it. It will only cost you a couple hours of your time. But if malware deletes your childhood photos or a document that you've been working on for months, you better have backups, because otherwise you're screwed. You can't go back in time to take these photos again.

Comment: Thank you @gronostaj for your clear answer. I am sorry not understanding your answer on the first attempt.

Comment: So is it really true to tell that linux has better security measures than windows? I mean youtubers like gardiner bryant, chris titus tech, distrotube and other linux youtubers tell that. @gronostaj

Comment: @jastyles They're both secure enough that it doesn't matter that much - it's the user that is the weakest link. No amount of excellent technical solutions will help if the user can be convinced to circumvent them and run the malware themselves, and that's the most common scenario nowadays I think. IMO we shouldn't be teaching people to use Linux, but to make good backups.

Comment: You are right and spot on. I also feel that. Thank you for your time @gronostaj